# How do I get a QScrollArea to scroll in one direction and honour the child size in the other

Tags: qt, qt5

I have a dialog with a programmatically generated menu consisting of flat QPushButtons in a QVBoxLayout. I want it to size to fit the buttons horizontally, and be scrollable vertically. I put this inside a QScrollArea and disabled the horizontal scrollbar. I want the scroll area width to match the menu width so that all of the buttons are fully shown width-wise, even if that means shrinking the buttons, but preferably keep the scroll area width big enough to contain the buttons' minimum size.

I am not getting the behaviour I want.

If I specify `false` for the QScrollArea's `widgetResizable` property then the scroll area is empty. Even if I enable horizontal scrolling, there are no scrollbars. My guess is that, even after adding buttons and calling `updateLayout()` on them, the menu widget has zero size.

If I specify `true` for the QScrollArea's `widgetResizable` property then the scroll child (the menu) is resized to be wider than it needs to be and wider than fits in the QScrollArea. My buttons are truncated.

Answer (score 2):

Override `QScrollArea.resizeEvent` and adjust `QScrollArea.widget()`'s width in it.

Comment: I found that merely resizing the client widget to fit the contents worked perfectly. Which is basically the same as you are suggesting, but is a once only operation and doesn't allow child widgets centred in the available space. However there must be a better solution that doesn't involve manually resizing the client widget.